# Does the Android Wear API have multi touch?

Tags: wear-os

I am building an android wear application and the interface would be greatly improved by multi touch, is this not currently possible with the Android Wear API? I am not finding anything in their references: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/wearable/package-summary.html

Answer (score 1):

This is completely possible. You just have to use [MotionEvent.getPointerCount](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html#getPointerCount()) and [MotionEvent.getPointerCoords](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html#getPointerCoords(int,%20android.view.MotionEvent.PointerCoords))

```
View.OnTouchListener onTouchListener = new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        int nbPoints = event.getPointerCount();

        // Coord of the first point
        MotionEvent.PointerCoords outPointerCoords = new MotionEvent.PointerCoords();
        event.getPointerCoords (1, outPointerCoords);
    }
};
```